# Moving average in Rust

Tags: algorithm, rust

I worked on implementing a simple moving average function in Rust, that works on a collection of year/revenue tuples:

```
fn compute_moving_average(window: &Box<&[(u32, u32)]>) -> (u32, f32) {
    let window_size = window.len();

    let current_year = window
        .iter()
        .nth((window_size as f32/ 2.0).floor() as usize)
        .unwrap().0;

    let sum = window
        .iter()
        .fold(0, |a, x| a + x.1) as f32 / window_size as f32;

    (current_year, sum)
}

fn extract_moving_average_for_year(year: u32, moving_average: &Vec<(u32, f32)>) -> Option<f32> {
    let x = moving_average
        .iter()
        .find(|a| a.0 == year);

    match x {
        Some(a) => Some(a.1),
        None => None,
    }
}

fn merge_moving_average(a: (u32, u32), avg: Option<f32>) -> (u32, u32, Option<f32>) {
    (a.0, a.1, avg)
}

fn main() {
    let vec = vec![
        (2003, 4),
        (2004, 6),
        (2005, 5),
        (2006, 8),
        (2007, 9),
        (2008, 5),
        (2009, 4),
        (2010, 3),
        (2011, 7),
        (2012, 8),
    ];

    let moving_average = vec
        .windows(5)
        .map(|a| compute_moving_average(&Box::new(a)))
        .collect::<Vec<_>>();

    vec
        .iter()
        .map(|a| merge_moving_average(*a, extract_moving_average_for_year(a.0, &moving_average)))
        .inspect(|a| println!("{:?}", a))
        .collect::<Vec<_>>();
}
```

Output:

```
(2003, 4, None)
(2004, 6, None)
(2005, 5, Some(6.4))
(2006, 8, Some(6.6))
(2007, 9, Some(6.2))
(2008, 5, Some(5.8))
(2009, 4, Some(5.6))
(2010, 3, Some(5.4))
(2011, 7, None)
(2012, 8, None)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I don't know why `compute_moving_average` takes a `Box`, much less why it would take a reference to one.
2. [Prefer `&[T]` over `&Vec<T>`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40006219/155423).
3. Why use floating point division with truncation when integer math does same, should be faster, and is shorter to write?
4. Don't use an iterator on a slice if you are just going to pull out the `nth` value; just index. Also bakes-in the `unwrap`.
5. I'd use `Iterator::map` and `Iterator::sum`.
6. Preserve the sum as an integer until the last moment, then convert it to floating point. This may or may not be a good idea depending on the input data.
7. Learn and love all the methods on `Option` and `Result`. For example, `Option::map` replaces the 4 lines of an explicit `match`.
8. `merge_moving_average` seems more trouble than it's worth; just inline it and provide better variable names.
9. There's no need to create a `Vec`; just pass in a slice of an array.
10. Can directly pass `compute_moving_average` with `map`, no closure or arguments needed.
11. It's more idiomatic to use `|&a|` in the closure argument instead of `*a` in the body when they are equivalent.
12. `Iterator::inspect` is more of a debugging tool than anything; use a `for` loop to drive an iterator for side effects.

```
fn compute_moving_average(window: &[(u32, u32)]) -> (u32, f32) {
    let window_size = window.len();

    let current_year = window[window_size / 2].0;

    let sum: u32 = window.iter().map(|&(_, val)| val).sum();
    let sum = sum as f32 / window_size as f32;

    (current_year, sum)
}

fn extract_moving_average_for_year(year: u32, moving_average: &[(u32, f32)]) -> Option<f32> {
    moving_average
        .iter()
        .find(|(yr, _)| yr == year)
        .map(|&(_, val)| val)
}

fn main() {
    let vec = [
        (2003, 4),
        (2004, 6),
        (2005, 5),
        (2006, 8),
        (2007, 9),
        (2008, 5),
        (2009, 4),
        (2010, 3),
        (2011, 7),
        (2012, 8),
    ];

    let moving_average = vec
        .windows(5)
        .map(compute_moving_average)
        .collect::<Vec<_>>();

    let moving_average = vec
        .iter()
        .map(|&(year, val)| (year, val, extract_moving_average_for_year(year, &moving_average)));

    for a in moving_average {
        println!("{:?}", a);
    }
}
```

---

Thoughts:

It would be interesting to see an implementation that doesn't use `windows`, but instead is based on an iterator.

If you know your slice is sorted, a [binary search](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.binary_search) might be more efficient.

Comment: Good points, I'm also still thinking about a solution without relying on `windows()` and instead work with iterators, do you have a general idea how it can be done? Would it make sense to add a custom function to `Iterator` like, instead of `.windows()` I could add `.windows_iter()` or something like that?

Comment: @Max if you were going to go that way, you may want to look at [itertools](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.5.7/itertools/). You may also want to try rolling your own, maybe writing an iterator that keeps a `Vec` of the last N numbers, and a sum, then you only have to add and remove one value per iteration...